# nginx redirect from aws public subnet to private subnet not working

Tags: redirect, amazon-web-services, nginx, vpc

I have an Amazon Web Services VPC set up with a public and private subnet.  I have an nginx server on the public subnet receiving DNS requests.  However, I want to redirect those requests to the private subnet webserver.  I tested the AWS/VPC routing from the nginx machine by using curl to the private subnet machine's private IP (not publically routable).  Curl returns the expected results.  However, when I have nginx do a return 301 to the same private IP, the results are search engine results as if the redirect is occurring outside of the routing table rules and is not recognized as a valid address.  Is there an nginx configuration that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - remember that a 'redirect' will respond to the client browser with a 301 or 302 code and the new address to access. If the address is not publicly routable, it will fail because it is the *browser* requesting the redirect address, not the proxy server (nginx). To prove this out, if you set your nginx to redirect to http://www.yahoo.com, it would work beautifully.

Instead, you should use the [proxy capabilities](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) of nginx - this means nginx receives requests, passes them to the proxied servers, retrieves responses from them, and sends them to the clients.

The most basic implementation is to create a location directive within your server directive in the nginx configuration file:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.5/;
}
```

This will pass all requests to the public IP on to private IP. Of course, there are numerous things you can do with request/response headers, resources, etc. A good starting point may be [Setting Up a Simple Proxy Server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy). [This link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html) also has some more configuration options and is a good example.